# Center with different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The site I'm working on has many Centers. Each Center can have zero or more courses. 
We need a signup form to create new centers.

#### Relation between User and Center

```
class Center < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :center

end
```

As you can see I'm using Devise, but it's not associated with Center, as we would like to be able to create different users for a Center with different privileges at some point.

Here goes the tricky part. The signup form should be composed of both User fields and Center fields. In the signup we must do:

- Create a new User
- Create a new Center
- Assign the new User to the New Center

The first approach I took was creating a new view (`views/center/new.html.erb`) and then I thought I would manage user fields (signing up the user) in Center's create action. However, I'm not sure how to include Devise in the equation (in CentersController#create).

How can I go with Devise including Center fields in the signup form? Which is the best way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to customize Devise views and controllers.

First generate those files:

```
rails g devise:views
rails g devise:controllers users
```

On the view for new registrations let's add a field for the Center:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  # ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :center %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :center %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Lastly you would need to create the Center on the RegistrationsController:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
    # assuming Center just has a name attr
    @user.create_center(name: params[:center])
    @user.save
  end

  # ...
end
```